How to set max-age in next image?
Currently data.imgSrc is, for example, example.com/image/1. I set the max-age to one month in the backend, but when I put this data.imgSrc in the next image, the max-age is not set.
Is there a way to set the max-age of the image URL set in the backend in the next image?
1.
// next.config.js
  images: {
    domains: ["~"],
    minimumCacheTTL: 86400,
  },




module.exports = {
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        // This works, and returns appropriate Response headers:
        source: '/(.*).jpg',
        headers: [
          {
            key: 'Cache-Control',
            value:
              'public, max-age=180, s-maxage=180, stale-while-revalidate=180',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        // This doesn't work for 'Cache-Control' key (works for others though):
        source: '/_next/image(.*)',
        headers: [
          {
            key: 'Cache-Control',
            // Instead of this value:
            value: 'public, max-age=180, s-maxage=180, stale-while-revalidate=180',
            // Cache-Control response header is `public, max-age=60` in production
            // and `public, max-age=0, must-revalidate` in development
          },
        ],
      },
    ]
  },
}

I tried both of these methods and they don't work. Is there a way to set max-age in the next image? I would appreciate it if you could let me know.
